# Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_run_automated_cron()

Tags: 7, migrations, database

I migrated my database from oracle to mysql and when linking it to my drupal the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function system_run_automated_cron() in /var/www/drupal/includes/common.inc on line 2732

Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  241712  {main}( )   .../index.php:0
2   0.1117  1842704 menu_execute_active_handler( )  .../index.php:21
3   0.1120  1844088 drupal_deliver_page( )  .../menu.inc:532
4   0.1123  1845064 drupal_deliver_html_page( ) .../common.inc:2589
5   0.1213  1858496 drupal_page_footer( )   .../common.inc:2705
```

Someone could help me solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason it hasn't defined [`system_run_automated_cron()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.module/function/system_run_automated_cron/7) in the core system module. It's just a matter of figuring out why. A couple of things to check are:

1. Since you moved the DB over, did all the tables get created correctly? Check for the `system` table for a row entry with the `name` column set to "system". Is the `status` column set to 1?
2. Does modules/system/system.module exist and is executable by the webserver?